designing to overcome 3rd party API rate limits in firebase functions
My product tracks the user's stock portfolio. I have created a Firebase function that is called every 24 hours. This function goes over the user's stock data and makes a call to a 3rd party API to get the latest stock prices etc. My code used to work fine until recently when the API vendor imposed a max 5 calls per minute rate limit. Now, with the current code, I start getting failures after the first 5 calls. How do I re-architect my code to add this wait after every 5 calls I make? Below is what the code looks like
exports.dailyNetworth = onSchedule("every 24 hours", async (event:any) => {
  ...

   for(let uid of validUsers.keys()){
      const finColRef = db.collection("users/" + uid + "/finance")
      const fQuerySnapshot = await finColRef.orderBy("Date",'desc').limit(1).get()
      fQuerySnapshot.forEach(async(doc:any) => {
        let data:any 
        data = doc.data()        
          const finance = new Finance()
          finance.assets = data.assets
               
          for(let ast of Object.keys(finance.assets['Stocks'])){
              const asset:Stock = finance.assets['Stocks'][ast]
              let lastUpdateDate = asset.lastUpdateDate.seconds

              const stkPrice:any = await findStockPrice(asset.Name, asset["Share Count"])
              if(stkPrice !== null){
                finance.assets[astClass][ast].value = stkPrice
                finance.assets[astClass][ast].lastUpdateDate = Timestamp.now()
              }
          }
      });
   }
});

The third-party API call method is like the below:
async function findStockPrice(symbol:string, quantity:number){
    let value = null
    try {
      const url = 'https://someurl.com?' + symbol
      const  header = {
        ...
      }

      const response = await fetch(url, {headers: header})
      const json = await response.json()

      const rate = json["rate"]
      value = quantity*rate

    } catch (error:any) {
      logger.error(error);
    }

  return value
}


Rate limiting like this isn't really a feature you can implement with code in Cloud Functions.  Also, it's a really bad idea for a function to just wait and do nothing, as you will be paying for all the time that each function invocation has to wait.  If you want rate limiting done well, you will need something far more sophisticated than a few more lines of code, such as a Cloud Task queue.

I understand what you are saying and yes I don't really want to literally implement the way I said. I just wanted to highlight what I want to achieve or the problem I need to overcome.

Cloud Functions is the wrong place to implement timing or scheduling. That should be performed by an application that implements Exponential backoff and retry logic.

You'll want to store the rate value that you get back from 'https://someurl.com?' + symbol, together with the timestamp at which you retrieve it, in some shared location (such as Cloud Firestore, which you already use).
Then when you need the rate again, you look it up from that database, and if it's less than 12 minutes old, use the stored value. If the stored value is older than 12 minutes, call the API again and store (and use) the updated rate value.

Thanks for responding. My problem is not about how to keep track of rate. my problem is that the cloud function is going over user data. it sees that user has 25 stocks. as the rate limit is 12 per minute. Now after making 12 calls, I need to kind of pause the cloud function for a minute before I can make more calls.

As Doug commented: you can't pause a cloud function, it's simply not the right mechanism for something like that.  --- If you continue using Cloud Functions, you'll need to decide how to response to those first calls that you can't correctly respond to (hint: consider sending a HTTP status 429 back). --- But even if you switch to another mechanism, you'll need to decide how you're going to prefill the database with rates from the 3rd party API you use.
